# matlab: inserting element after element?

Tags: arrays, matlab, insert, indexing

Is there a way to insert an element into an array after verifying a certain element value? For example, take

```
A = [0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
```

After each 1 in the array, I want to insert another 1 to get

```
Anew = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
```

However I want a way to code this for a general case (any length 1 row array and the ones might be in any order).

Answer (score 5):

```
A = [0 0 1 1 0 1 1];

i = (A == 1);  % Test for number you want insert after
t = cumsum(i);              
idx = [1 (2:numel(A)) + t(1:end-1)];

newSize = numel(A) + sum(i);
N = ones(newSize,1)*5;             % Make this number you want to insert

N(idx) = A
```

Output:

```
N =

     0     0     1     5     1     5     0     1     5     0
```

I made the inserted number 5 and split things onto multiple lines so it's easy to see what's going on.

If you wanted to do it in a loop (and this is how I would do it in real life where no-one can see me showing off)

```
A = [0 0 1 1 0 1 0];

idx = (A == 1);  % Test for number you want insert after
N = zeros(1, numel(A) + sum(idx));
j = 1;
for i = 1:numel(A)
    N(j) = A(i);
    if idx(i)
        j = j+1;
        N(j) = 5;       % Test for number you want to insert after
    end
    j = j+1;
end

N
```

Output:

N =

```
 0     0     1     5     1     5     0     1     5     0
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is not the most elegant, but it'll answer your question...

```
 A=[0 0 1 1 0 1 0];
 AA=[];
 for ii=1:length(A);
     AA=[AA A(ii)];
     if A(ii)
         AA=[AA 1];
     end
 end
```

I'm sure there will be also a vectorized way...

Comment: The only problem with that is AA grows every iteration, which will make it very slow for large vectors. If you could preallocate AA there would be no problem, but then the concatenation doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, it is no good for big arrays, as I said already, there is a vectorized way, and you showed one. I was thinking also about accumarray, but I'm not sure \ not experienced how to do it with that function...

Comment: Not vectorized, yet very clear for the reader. Definitely a good answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
>> A = [0 0 1 1 0 1 0] 
>>
>> sumA = sum(A);
>> Anew = zeros(1, 2*sumA+sum(~A));
>> I = find(A) + (0:sumA-1);
>> Anew(I) = 1;
>> Anew(I+1) = 8.2;

Anew =
    0  0  1  8.2  1  8.2  0  1  8.2  0
```